# Suggest me good way to avoid outofmemory error in android

Tags: android, android-studio, out-of-memory

I'm new to android please suggest me a good way to optimise images or some library that I use to set image in my app without getting out of memory error...

any kind help appreciated.

Thanks any advance :)

Comment: Take a look on "Glide" library or "Picasso".

Comment: Use [Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1091/glide#t=201705260739144828845)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it depends

1). If u r displaying images base on URL in Recyclerview , Gridview etc.

U can use imageloader libraries for that according to ur need

Below are libraries link choose which u want to use:

Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Picasso:https://github.com/square/picasso

Universal image loader: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Load

Now which to choose I personally recommend glide.if u want to load big size image than go with universal image loader,if u want to go with small images than go with picasso

2). If u r going to use same bitmap in different places than u can use ***Bitmap caching***

**Bitmap caching techniques**

1. LruCache
2. DiskCache

3). Some settings which can help u for OutOfMemory error:

In manifest file u can set largeHeap="true"

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Mall"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo_for_up"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Hope this answer help u..if u want any other help u can ask for it

Comment: @PankazKumar Happy to help u my friend